# My project is not giving error but not working- Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a listTile, but results showing blank.
The program was running before but now not working.

here is my code :

```
class durum extends StatelessWidget {
CollectionReference recipes = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(emailadresi);
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: currentIndex,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'Anasayfa',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.devices_other),
        label: 'Saha Yönetimi',
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
        label: 'Cihazlarım',
      ),
     
    ],
  ),
    body:
    Container(
      height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("lib/assets/giris.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
  
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(children: <Widget>[
           Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0,bottom:5),
         child: Image.asset(
              "lib/assets/logo_ust.png",
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 90,
          )
          ),
            Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: recipes.snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Text("Loading");
            }
                      return Scrollbar(
              
            child: ListView.builder(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), 
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount:snapshot.data?.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return  Container(
                      height: 100,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                  child:ListTile(
                  leading: Image.asset(
        "lib/assets/logo_ust.png",
        height: 40,
        width: 60,
      ),
                  title: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]['T_isim']),
                  trailing: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]['Durum']),
                   ));
              },
            )
      );}),
     )
  ]))));}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap ListView.Builder with sizedbox and give it fixed height and width
(width is optional but you have to add fixed height)

```
SizedBox(
          height : 300,
          width : 500
          child : ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), 
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount:snapshot.data?.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              return  Container(
                    height: 100,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                child:ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset(
                  "lib/assets/logo_ust.png",
                  height: 40,
                  width: 60,
                ),
                title: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]['T_isim']),
                trailing: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]['Durum']),
                ));
            },
          )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. I took your suggestion into consideration. Also, I realized that I had accidentally removed my necessary internet permissions in the program. Adding the internet permissions again fixed my problem.